# Access Vista Share from RHEL 5.3 Server - mount error 110

Tags: windows-vista, rhel5, cifs

I am trying to access a file share on a Vista box from a RHEL 5.3 server.

The Vista box is part of a domain, but it has two NIC cards. One is on the 158.x.x.x network. The other card is on the 10.10.10.x network. RHEL box is on the 10.10.10.x network. The 10.10.10.x network is ***NOT*** part of the domain.

The IP of my Vista box is 10.10.10.50 while RHEL box is 10.10.10.60.

I can ping back and forth to both machines.

I executed this command from the RHEL box:

```
mount -t cifs -o username=username,password=password //hostname/transfer /mnt/transfer
```

`/mnt/transfer` does exist on the RHEL box.

`hostname` is defined in `/etc/hosts`

`transfer` does exist on the Vista box.

I verifed that the Windows Firewall Service is not running on the Vista box.

Username and Password are a valid password as that is the Domain password for my username.

But, I still get the **mount error 110** from `cifs`.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said the Vista box is part of a domain, therefore you must also pass the domain name or the mount command will attempt to authenticate to the **Vista local machine's** SAM database, instead of the domain's.

Try your command this way:

```
mount -t cifs -o username=username,password=password,domain=domain //hostname/transfer /mnt/transfer
```

Transfer may exist on the target Vista box as a folder name, but you should ensure that this is the name of the share as well. If you're on the Vista machine, open explorer and go to \127.0.0.1\, and ensure that the share is named transfer. You can change the name of the share in the Sharing tab for the folder.

You can also see if your credentials and everything are working by trying to list shares:

`smbclient -L -U username -W domain host`

This should prompt you for your password.

Comment: Verified by going to \\127.0.0.1 that transfer is the name of the share. I added the domain name, but I still get mount 110 error.

Comment: See edit for smbclient command to test if the share is visible from the RHEL box

Comment: It says NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME (I used the IP address)

Comment: Anything in /var/log/messages ?

Comment: It says: "CIFS VFC: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation".